# jQuery Mask for Documents Leading Zeroes and Right to Left

Tags: jquery, mask

Hy people,

I´m using jquery.maskedit plugin for few fields in my application and I cannot figure the way to compose a mask like this:

Document: 000000-0

I need the field to be filled always with zeroes and the direction from right to left.

Is there any jQuery plugin or someone knows how to setup this mask using jquery.maskedit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer: there are bugs. But this is one way to do it.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/donmccurdy/3sQrm/)

```
$.fn.specialMask = function () {
  this.on('click focus', function () { 
      var self = this; 
      setTimeout(function() {self.value = self.value;}, 15); //move cursor to end
  }) 
  .on('keypress', function (e) {
      var 
          num,
          $this = $(this),
          cur = $this.val().match(/Document: ([0-9]*\-[0-9])/); //get value

      if (cur[1][0] !== '0') { return; } //input is full

      if (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) { //numeric keys
          num = e.keyCode - 48;
      } else if (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) { //numpad
          num = e.keyCode - 96;
      } else { 
          return;   
      }
      cur = cur[1].replace('-', '').substr(1) + '-' + num; //shift value left
      $this.val('Document: ' + cur); //update input
  });
};

$('#tehInput').mask('Document: 999999-9', {placeholder: '0'}).specialMask(); // initialize the input
```

I used jquery.maskedinput.js as I couldn't find the maskedit plugin you mentioned. If you have a link, try adding it to the jsfiddle - i'm hoping this might work similarly with other plugins?

Right-to-left replacement of placeholders is tricky to fake (as you can see above) if it's not built into the plugin. A somewhat easier trick I did once was to make a fake input like this:

```
<div class="input-wrapper">
    <span class="input-pre"></span>
    <input type="text">
</div>
```

Then you can style the wrapper to look like a normal input, style the actual input to be blank white with no border, and focus the input when a 'click' event happens on the wrapper. Put your leading 0's into the pre-span, keep it updated with JS, and no one will be the wiser!